# Is it rude to call a gay person "homosexual?"

Tags: expressions, offensive-language, politeness, sexual-minorities

I was talking to one of my co-workers today. We have two homosexual persons in our office. I forgot one's name, so I asked my co-worker, "What's his name?" My co-worker said "Who?", and I replied, "one of the homosexual persons."

Then, my co-worker told me that it is rude to call them "homosexual". I used "homosexual" because I thought it was better than "gay". Am I wrong?

Comment: Why not just say "the guy over there"?

Comment: @Ray J. Stomach // You're right. my fault.

Comment: @FumbleFingers why do you say that? The stated goals of most LGBT organizations is to promote acceptance and understanding of all sexual orientations and lifestyles. Acceptance includes the freedom to comfortably identify with your orientation without any  stigma. As long as the exchange wasn't rude or openly hostile/derogatory/prejudicial, it should be no different than mentioning their hair color or what they are wearing. Why would asking what the "gay guys name" is be any different than asking "what the redhead's name" is?

Comment: @crasic it isn't any different. And "redhead" seems to be equally inappropriate.

Comment: @lalli only when referring to a woman and I thought we were talking about a male :D (isn't society funny)

Comment: @crasic: I know for a fact that some redheads don't much like people calling attention to that particular characteristic. Just as some black people would prefer not to be identified as such for purposes of distinguishing them from whites. And would you identify some particular woman in the office as "the one with large breasts"? You've obviously been working in some unusual offices.

Comment: @crasic: I sympathize with your way of thinking, but I agree with @Fumble. It is slightly inappropriate, for two reasons: 1. you don't usually point out people as "readhead" either, unless to someone you know well, in which case "the Jew" would go too; 2. homosexuality involves sex, which is a bit taboo. I don't care what LGBT organizations say, or gays who walk around butt naked in some parade: I have not chosen them to represent me, and the taboo on sex is still generally observed, including by most homosexuals. // And what if some effeminate guy insists that he is straight? It happens.

Comment: @Cerberus: Absolutely. You can't really help noticing if someone is black/fat/excessively camp/etc., but it's generally considered rude to identify people as such, even if *you personally* don't have a negative attitude to the characteristic in question. And it's a cop-out to say it's okay if everyone else says they're happy with the usage; there may be people who have serious hangups with it, but feel awkward about speaking up.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Agreed. But I do indicate people by such terms to good friends. In Dutch, everyone I know uses the word *neger* privately, which is equivalent to English *nigger*, though slightly less controversial. That is, the majority of Dutchmen would be shocked to hear it and never use it themselves (but those PC people aren't in our circles), and hardly anyone would ever use the word on television. The idea is that you know your friends aren't racists, so you can freely use what term comes up intuitively. But that usually doesn't apply to the office.

Comment: @Cerberus: Of course. Among close friends there's often no need to observe the conventions. But close friends don't need advice from a site like EL&U telling them how they should speak. People in offices like OP's certainly do though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Very true.

Comment: Come on guys... are you seriously saying that it's rude to call someone redhead? I don't see why that would be different from saying "the dude with black hair". Personally I don't have a problem with the use of "gay" or "homosexual" either as used in this context, unless the person minds to be called gay, which he shouldn't because there's absolutely nothing wrong with that, as there is nothing wrong with having red hair.

Comment: @nico people object to being defined by a single characteristic, so the tendency in polite society is to move towards using “people-first” terminology—a *child with autism* instead of an *autistic child*, *people of color* instead of *black people*, *woman with red hair* instead of *redhead*, etc.

Comment: @nohat: I think that's very hypocritical. I don't mind being called the curly haired guy. I am, so what? For me it's more the way one says it than the specific world used. Again, this is just our society wanting to be politically correct at all costs. Useless if the correctness is only limited to words. I just have a normal relationship with my gay friends and continue to call them gay and they don't mind.For example, I live in a fairly international city and it's absolutely normal to refer to people by their nationality (the Swedish guy, the Algerian girl). I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rudeness is perceptual.  The co-worker has associated the (correct) term "homosexual" with negative connotations.  The term "gay" is a slang word for homosexuality.  Therefore, the word you selected is more appropriate.

The bottom line is your co-worker has personal issues with the word, "homosexual".  Ironically, many homosexuals also have this problem.  Logically speaking, the matter should be moot.  However, arguing a emotionally charged matter such as this is rather difficult, and usually does not end well.

My advice is to simply use the word "gay" around that particular person, to make your life easier.

Comment: @Mike Christian: I'm not sure it's correct to say that **gay** is a slang word nowadays. As it happens, my gay brother received an official form from his employer today (NHS in UK), and one entry to be filled in is a multi-choice with options **Heterosexual, Bisexual, Lesbian, Gay, Prefer not to say**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That is freaky in several ways! 1. How is this relevant for his employer? It's none of his business, in my opinion. 2. I think *gay* is still more slangy than the other words used. It should be either *Heterosexual, Bisexual, Homosexual, That is Private*, or *straight, bi, gay, I'm in the closet*.

Comment: @Cerberus: Freaky or not, the NHS is one of the biggest employers in the world. In fact it's *the* biggest employer of Anglophones, by some considerable margin. Personally if I'd seen that one of the boxes was *I'm in the closet* I'd have fallen off my perch, but *gay* is definitely part of the standard lexicon in the UK today, even if it's not there (yet) in the US.

Comment: and btw one reason why it's relevant is the NHS has to be *much* more careful about the welfare of both staff and patients where gays are involved because they're much more likely to have HIV / hepatitis / etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Let me rephrase *slangy* as *informal*: don't you agree that *gay* is more informal than *heterosexual*? I just found the words in the list incongruous. // Okay, I see why the NHS might want to know that. However, I do think that stuff is private. If the risk warrants it, they should have every employee take an HIV test every six months (shouldn't be expensive); if not, I really don't think meddling with people's sexuality is a good idea. And how would they formulate policy? Gays shouldn't be surgeons?

Comment: @Cereberus. Many employers use surveys like this anonymously to check whether they have any implicit biases in their hiring practices. They check whether the ratios in the workforce match the ratios in the world at large; if they don't, they revise their hiring practices to weed out discrimination. (Note that "positive discrimination" is illegal in the UK, but you can choose to advertise preferentially in certain media, etc.) How this applies to sexual orientation, where the ratios in society at large are very hard to estimate, I don't know.

Comment: @Mike Christian, I've just posted an answer strongly disagreeing with your assertion that the word *homosexual* is "more appropriate". Have a glance at it and see whether I've convinced you. I thought, since I mentioned your answer in mine, it was polite to comment here to let you know.

Comment: Yes, there are many alternatives.  However, the question specifically targeted the words "gay" and "homosexual".  *Homosexual* is autological (a self-describing word).  If you set the Waybac machine's dial to 1940, you'll find the word "gay" means "having or showing a merry, lively mood: gay spirits; gay music."  Thus, "homosexual" is both autological and historically more accurate.

Comment: @Mike Christian, Beware the etymological fallacy! The history of the word *gay* is actually quite fascinating. And, contrary to some assertions I've seen, it wasn't "taken" by the gay activists. The change in meaning was natural, if non-obvious.

Answer (score 22):

Well, I suppose it's slightly better than *gay*, which is now used derogatorily quite often, whereas *homosexual* has a more scientific detached feel to it.

However, I wouldn't say that makes it ok to use in a context like that—it makes it feel like you know them only by their sexual orientation and not by who they are as people, so it is still sensitive in that respect. It would be more acceptable to use a different quality—perhaps answering "him" while gesturing in his direction, or perhaps "the one working on the [so-and-so] project"; these alternatives make it seem like you're not concentrating on sexual orientation.

Comment: +1 for identifying what the real problem likely was -- using a controversial trait to identify someone instead of something conservative (e.g., "the guy wearing the white shirt").

Comment: // ah...you're right. totally agree. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: When "gay" is used as a derogatory term these days it is not in the context of sexual orientation.

Answer (score 6):

I can't speak for your co-worker, but the part that would have bothered **me** about that statement was that you were identifying someone to a person who didn't know them by something that is logically a non-physical characteristic.

So basically **you are asking your friend (and anyone else in earshot) to look around for someone who "looks homosexual"**.

Yes, that would have bothered me too. I have enough trouble fighting the innate bigotry society has instilled in me as it is, without having to deal with others inviting me to indulge in it.

Answer (score 5):

Many gay people, including myself, find the word *homosexual* somewhat offensive because of the way it has been coopted by professional anti-gay activists such as the National Organization for Marriage and the Family Research Council. One News Now, a news website run by the homophobic American Family Association, once got into trouble for taking a AP press release about the sprinter Tyson Gay and publishing it as "Tyson Homosexual". They have an [automatic filter](http://revealingerrors.com/tyson_homosexual) which converts *gay* to *homosexual*. Why do you think they feel the need to have that filter? Why are homophobes uncomfortable with the word *gay*?

It's because *gay* and *homosexual* don't mean quite the same thing. Homosexuality is an orientation. A gay person (note that both words can be used as nouns, but many gay people are uncomfortable with that) is comfortable with his sexuality. He has established, to borrow the language of the religious right, a "gay identity".

Gay news blogs such as Box Turtle Bulletin and human rights organisations use the word *gay* throughout their writing.

Words mean things, even if the difference is subtle; and this difference in usage has an effect:

> A recent CBS/New York Times poll found
>   that 70 percent of Americans are in
>   favor of gay men and lesbians serving
>   in the military. Hooray for progress!
>   Unfortunately, the same poll found
>   that only 59 percent of Americans are
>   in favor of homosexuals serving in the
>   military.

[Salon](http://www.salon.com/life/broadsheet/2010/02/12/gay_homosexual).

Mike Christian's answer is therefore shown to be wrong. The word *homosexual* is not "more appropriate". It's not used in a human rights context; it's not used in a cultural identity context; and it's falling out of favour in a medical context (they use "men who have sex with men" instead, to cover all bases). The only context in which the word *homosexual* is still commonly used is an anti-gay context. Avoid it.

Comment: Hmm.  I'd come to the conclusion that "homosexual" was an orientation, and "gay" was a lifestyle.  By which definition I am homosexual, and entirely comfortable with it.  That said, I rarely bother with that distinction and use the terms interchangeably anyway.

Comment: @Rhodri, "The gay lifestyle" is another phrase of the religious right. No one can ever really define what the "gay lifestyle" is. I'd say that *gay* is an identity, in that you're gay if you think you are. So a gay person is homosexual and comfortable with it. Of course, all these words have fuzzy edges. That said, I've rarely seen *homosexual* used as a self-descriptor. Even homosexual fundies don't use it as a self-descriptor. They describe themselves as "experiencing unwanted same-sex attraction".

Comment: I think what I'm trying to get across is that "gay" is a self-descriptor used by people who consider their sexuality to be a defining feature of their life (ditto, to a much lesser extent, "straight").  It's not a defining feature of my life, any more than my handedness is; I just happen to find men sexually attractive.

Comment: I truly appreciate your rebuttal!  Point well made.  I enjoy a lively, civil debate, which is becoming increasingly rare among denizens of the Internet.

Comment: http://www.boxturtlebulletin.com/2011/08/18/36222 "Conservative churches welcome homosexuals."

Comment: I'm not the only one who thinks [the words have very different connotations](http://gaylife.about.com/b/2011/09/05/gay-from-happy-to-homosexual.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Oh, for heaven's sake. Speak to your Gay/Homosexual co-worker and ask HIM what language he prefers and why. Strike up a genuine friendship and get some real answers to your question. He probably won't bite if you approach him like another human being and not merely as a member of some group.

Comment: Well.... he might bite. Rarr. *Nibble* ;)